# How to Get same Connection id in django for every file

Tags: python, mysql, django, connection, database-connection

Every time I run my Django webservice the **connection** (django and MySQL connector) is same for every python function that I call but **Connection_id** from MySQL workbench is different for every python function. My temporary table keeps dropping from the DB which was created from a python function A and has to be accessed by another independent python function B at a later point of time from a different webservice. I guess the temporary table is being dropped as a result of new instances(connection_id) getting generated in the MySQL DB everytime I run a webservice to call my python functions.

**Example outputs of connections:**

Mysql Connection ID: 18423
django connection: <django.utils.connection.ConnectionProxy object at 0x00000203C0C84340>        mysql connection: <mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x00000203C1B7C070>

Mysql Connection ID: 18424
django connection: <django.utils.connection.ConnectionProxy object at 0x00000203C0C84340>        mysql connection: <mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x00000203C1B7C070>

**Expectation Example outputs of connections:**

Mysql Connection ID: 18423
django connection: <django.utils.connection.ConnectionProxy object at 0x00000203C0C84340>        mysql connection: <mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x00000203C1B7C070>

**same nexttime**

Mysql Connection ID: 18423
django connection: <django.utils.connection.ConnectionProxy object at 0x00000203C0C84340>        mysql connection: <mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x00000203C1B7C070>

Please help me with this.